# What is the correct place to put mock demand statements in Grails tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I am working with grails and writing tests using Spock framework.
I am trying to figure out what is the correct section (given, where, then, setup ...) in the test to put mock code.

For example, is the following correct?

```
void "test Something"() {
    given:
       //build mock and add demand statements...

    when:
       //Call method
}
```

Comment: Should be in setup/given as it is part of the setup. Demands can be verified on the mock control in `then` block as part of the assertion. If you are using `Mock` API from spock instead of `mockFor` from Grails then it is feasible to specify demands while Mocking/Stubbing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to put my demands in the then section unless I have complex mocks in which case I put them in the given, but they will work both places.

```
void "test Something"() {
    given:
       def myService = Mock(MyService)
       mainThing.myService = myService

    when:
       mainThing.doCall()

    then:
       1 * myService.call() >> 'value'
}
```